# Como limpar os dados armazenados na memória, no cache ou então resetar uma aplicação (App) no android studio?

Tags: java, android, sql, android-studio

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo em android studio e preciso resolver esse problema.

Eu estou usando um banco de dados interno em SqlOpenHelper para armazenar os produtos escolhidos pelo usuário e mostrar em um carrinho de compras. São no máximo três produtos que o usuário pode comprar por entrega.

Mas o que está acontecendo é que, da primeira vez que o usuário loga no app ele funciona perfeitamente e só permite que o usuário adicione no máximo três produtos no carrinho de compras. Entretanto, se por eventualidade o usuário  já tiver com seu carrinho cheio e apertar o botão "Home" do aparelho e voltar no app novamente, ele automaticamente permite ao usuário acrescentar mais três produtos além do limite e eu não quero isso.

O que eu quero é saber o que eu preciso fazer para "resetar" o app, se por eventualidade, o usuário clicar no botão Home do aparelho e não no botão certo para ele sair?

Exite algum método específico que ao finalizar o app ele resete toda memória?

Eu já ouvi falar no `onDestroy(){...}`, mas eu acho que ele é só para detruir a activity e não é isso que eu quero. Eu quero que independente da activity que o usuário esteja, se o app fechar, ele reseta.

Answer (score 2):

O `onDestroy` não serve para destruir uma `Activity`. Ele é executado sempre que uma activity é finalizada. Para finalizar uma activity, você usa o `finish()`.

Independente da `Activity` que você usar, `onDestroy` da activity será chamado toda vez que essa activity for finalizada. Se o seu aplicativo tiver 5 activitys abertas e o aplicativo inteiro for finalizado, todas as 5 activitys chamarão o seu método `onDestroy`. Mesmo que eles nãos estejam sobrescrito.

Então, dentro do método você pode criar o código para limpar os dados.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    /* ... Códigos .... */
    limparDados();
}
```

Você pode usar também o `onPause`. Este método é chamado quando a activity está em "segundo plano" e você já poderia limpar os dados naquele instante, não importando se ele abriu uma nova activity ou apertou a home do celular.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    /* ... Códigos .... */
    limparDados();
}
```

Se você quiser resetar o aplicativo quando o usuário voltar, você pode usar o `onRestart`:

```
@Override
public void onRestart(){
    super.onRestart();
    // cria uma nova activity
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MinhaActivity.class));
    finish(); // finaliza a activity aberta
}
```

Apesar de ter sido isso que foi pedido, essa não é a solução mais viável, pois ao meu ver, o maior problema está no seu algorítimo. Na lógica dele. Uma condição lógica em algum lugar resolveria esse problema para não deixá-lo adicionar mais produtos.